# How to change the size of the text of UIbutton in monotouch?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, xamarin.ios

I tried the code

```
UIbutton *bt = new UIbutton;
bt.Font = UIFont.SystemFontSize(35);
```

But I keep getting a compilation error "Font size is inaccessible due to protection level."
Any workaround?

Answer (score 6):

The error message is far from ideal, but `SystemFontSize` is property that returns a float, not a method that returns a `UIFont`.

For that you want:

```
UIButton button = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
bt.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (35)
```